# How do I explictly require a Trait for all arguments of a function in a procedural macro?

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

## The short version

The short version is: when writing a procedural macro `wrap` that wraps around a function (kind of the way the [trace crate](https://docs.rs/trace/latest/trace/) does), what's the best way to require that all arguments implement a specific trait?

## The problem

`trace` expands to calls to `println!("{:?}", i)` so with:

```
struct MyType(u32);

#[trace]
fn foo(i: MyType) {
    println!("MyType: {}", i.0);
}
```

I get

```
error[E0277]: `MyType` doesn't implement `Debug`
  --> src/main.rs:10:8
   |
9  | #[trace]
   | ------- in this procedural macro expansion
10 | fn foo(i: MyType) {
   |        ^ `MyType` cannot be formatted using `{:?}`
   |
   = help: the trait `Debug` is not implemented for `MyType`
```

Which is nice and explicit: it shows the error in the argument declaration, and says that MyType should implement Debug.

Now I'm trying to do the same but by expanding to something like `MyTrait::my_trait_method(&i)`, and still get  basically the same error message.

## What I tried

So far the best I could do is adding Where clauses in an expansion generated through the `quote!` macro (I'm still figuring out how to use the `syn` crate so it's still quite hardcoded), at least I do get an explicit message saying that `MyType` does not implement `MyTrait`, but the error is reported on the macro rather than on the argument definition :

```
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn wrap(_macro_args: TokenStream, input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let func = parse_macro_input!(input as syn::ItemFn);
    let orig_name = func.sig.ident.to_string();
    let params: Punctuated<Pat, Token![,]> = func
        .sig
        .inputs
        .iter()
        .map(|input| match input {
            FnArg::Typed(PatType { pat: t, .. }) => t.as_ref().clone(),
            _ => panic!("Unexpected input for function {orig_name}: {input:?}"),
        })
        .collect();


    let pattern = "{:?}, ".repeat(params.len());
    quote! {
        fn foo(i: MyType) where MyType: MyTrait{
            //i.my_trait_method();
            println!(#pattern, #params);
        }
    }
    .into()
}
```

```
#[trace]
fn foo(i: MyType) {
    println!("MyType: {}", i.0);
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `MyType: MyTrait` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:11:1
   |
11 | #[wrap]
   | ^^^^^^^ the trait `MyTrait` is not implemented for `MyType`
```

Is generating Where clauses the way to go (I'll do that properly if that's the case), or is there a better way to require a specific trait for all arguments of a function parsed in a proc_macro ?

Comment: Why won't you look at how it is implemented in the `trace` library?

Comment: Well, if I do the same thing as `trace`, which is expand into `println!("{:?}", i)` (which I still do in my code), I get the same explicit error message, so I'm guessing there's something special about `println!` or `Debug` that makes the error message behave the way I want.

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand that you're after this exact wording, not just wanting the compiler to show `Debug` and not `MyTrait`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Chayim Friedman's answer is correct, I wanted to add that you can still use identifiers and spans to improve your error.

In the below code, instead of hardcoding the Trait, you create an identifier and point to the 'span' of parameters (basically the original location of those parameters in your code). The rest of the code is almost unchanged.

```rust
// ...
use syn::Ident;

#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn wrap(_macro_args: TokenStream, input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let func = parse_macro_input!(input as syn::ItemFn);
    let orig_name = func.sig.ident.to_string();
    let params: Punctuated<Pat, Token![,]> = func
        .sig
        .inputs
        .iter()
        .map(|input| match input {
            FnArg::Typed(PatType { pat: t, .. }) => t.as_ref().clone(),
            _ => panic!("Unexpected input for function {orig_name}: {input:?}"),
        })
        .collect();

    let trait_ident = Ident::new("MyTrait", params.span());

    let pattern = "{:?}, ".repeat(params.len());
    quote! {
        fn foo(i: MyType) where MyType: #trait_ident {
            println!(#pattern, #params);
        }
    }
    .into()
}
```

Now, with the following code, also based on your example:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyType(u32);

trait MyTrait {}

// activate if you do not want an error
// impl MyTrait for MyType {}

#[wrap]
fn foo(i: MyType) {
    println!("MyType: {}", i.0);
}

fn main() {}
```

You will get back this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `MyType: MyTrait` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:12:8
   |
12 | fn foo(i: MyType) {
   |        ^ the trait `MyTrait` is not implemented for `MyType`
   |
   = help: see issue #48214
```

Which looks a lot more helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that.

`Debug` is special because is in the standard library, and the standard library can use unstable internal-only features. It uses one, `#[rustc_on_unimplemented]`, to specify a custom error message.

[Here's how it looks like](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.71.0/src/core/fmt/mod.rs.html#536-544):

```rust
#[rustc_on_unimplemented(
    on(
        crate_local,
        label = "`{Self}` cannot be formatted using `{{:?}}`",
        note = "add `#[derive(Debug)]` to `{Self}` or manually `impl {Debug} for {Self}`"
    ),
    message = "`{Self}` doesn't implement `{Debug}`",
    label = "`{Self}` cannot be formatted using `{{:?}}` because it doesn't implement `{Debug}`"
)]
```

You can do something similar for your traits, but it will require you to stick with nightly, and this is an undocumented internal-only feature. I don't recommend that you'll do that.

[There is an RFC to allow you to use that in your code](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/3366-diagnostic-attribute-namespace.html), but it is not yet implemented as of now.

Comment: Then it looks like generating `Where` clauses is the way to go. I wasn't sure that my first attempt wasn't in bad practice territory but the internal way isn't available right now. Thanks